# Too many connections to the DB in Heroku-postgress

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

In my code I can't find an error, but something wrong. Every few seconds in the heroku-postgresql there is +1 connection. The one place, where it can happens is:

```
def dis_online_users():
    date_time_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    users = Users.objects.filter(when_online__lt=date_time_now, is_online=True)
    for user in users:
        user.is_online = False
        user.save()
    return True


def start_background():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(dis_online_users, 'interval', seconds=60)
    scheduler.add_job(remove_deleted_messages, 'interval', hours=48)
    scheduler.add_job(delete_null_chats, 'interval', hours=48)
    scheduler.start()

start_background()
```

But I can't understand what's wrong there. Can you?

Comment: How is this code triggered? What is BackgroundScheduler?

Comment: @DanielRoseman BackgroundScheduler is the object in "apscheduler.schedulers.background". This code is triggered by calling a function "start_background()" in the bottom of my "views.py" file. I cant understand why it doesn't work properly. Finction dis_online_users() doesn't close connection, as I can see.